# Summation of the infinite series $ 1+(1+a)b + (1+a+a^2)b^2 + (1+a+a^2+a^3)b^3........ $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The series is

> $$
> 1+(1+a)b + (1+a+a^2)b^2 + (1+a+a^2+a^3)b^3........
> $$

where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers between $1$ and $-1$.

This is **homework**.

I tried to solve it by substituting the special case $a=b$ (to match it with given option since it is a MCQ), but when I expand the series, it seems to be divergent.

The options are

> (A)$$(1-a)^{-1}(1-b)^{-1}$$ (B)$$(1-a)^{-1}(1-ab)^{-1}$$ (C)$$(1-ab)^{-1}(1-b)^{-1}$$ (D)$$(1-a)^{-1}(1-b)^{-1}(1-ab)^{-1}$$

Comment: A nice trick in such situations is to use $1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})$, So what did you get when you used $a=b$? Did you try $a=0$ or $b=0$?

Comment: Putting $a=0$ gives either option (A) or (B). When I put $a=b$ I got $1+ a+a+a+a+a+a....+a^2+a^2+a^2.....$ and so on

Comment: When $a=b=x$, say, I think you should try again to make sure you have the correct expansion. It may help to use a convenient value of $x$ such as $.01$ so the series is $1 + (1+.01).01 + (1+.01+.0001).0001 + \dots$

Comment: okay:) Ill get back by today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{(1-a^{r+1})b^r}{1-a}$$

$$\iff(1-a)S_n=\sum_{r=0}^nb^r-a\sum_{r=0}^n(ab)^r$$

Now  for $|r|<1,$  $$\sum_{u=0}^\infty ar^u=\dfrac a{1-r}$$

Answer (score 5):

The general term of the sum can be written

$$\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}b^n.$$  Factor out the $1/(a-1)$ and distribute
the $b^n$ and now you have two geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the sum as a double sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+(1+a)b &+& (1+a+a^2)b^2 + (1+a+a^2+a^3)b^3 + \cdots \\&=& \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b^i \sum_{j=0}^{i} a^j 
\end{eqnarray*}
now invert the order of the plums & perform the geometric sums
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b^i \sum_{j=0}^{i} a^j = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  \sum_{i=j}^{\infty}   b^i a^j =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  \frac{  b^j a^j}{(1-b)}= \color{red}{\frac{1}{(1-b)(1-ab)}}.
\end{eqnarray*}